# why do some short form of conditionals work in python and some don't?

Tags: python, python-2.7, conditional-statements

Take the example:

```
 a = "foo" if True else "bar"
```

This executes fine and without problems.
now take:

```
print("foo") if True else print("bar")
```

This throws an error.

I assume the first one works like a ternary operator. Is there a way to write the second statement without resorting to the full length:

```
if True:
    print("foo")
else:
    print("bar")
```

Something akin to Perl's

```
print("foo") if True
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. All paths of a conditional *expression*, must be evaluatable.
2. In Python 2.7, [`print` is a *statement*](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#print), not a function. So, it cannot be evaluated as an expression.

Since `print` statement violates point 2, it cannot be used. But you can do

```
print "foo" if True else "bar"
```

In Python 3.x, [`print` is a *function*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print), so you can write as you mentioned in the question

```
print("foo") if True else print("bar")
```

Since `print` is a function in Python 3.x, the result of the function call will be the result of the evaluation of the function call expression. You can check this like this

```
print(print("foo") if True else print("bar"))
# foo
# None
```

`print` function doesn't explicitly return anything. So, by default, it returns `None`. The result of evaluating `print("foo")` is `None`.

Comment: i guess things like `continue` are considered statements? the idea was to not have to write the whole thing in cases like `continue if foo.startswith("#")`

Comment: @TitoCandelli: You can see the list of statements in [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/index.html).

Comment: @TitoCandelli Yes, `continue`, `break` and `pass` are also statements. Statements can be executed, but can not be evaluated.

Comment: and one can `from __future__ import print_function` in [python 2.6 or later](https://docs.python.org/2/library/__future__.html) if necessary.